# Getting `rescue in rbuf_fill': Timeout::Error using httparty with ruby middleman

Tags: ruby, json, api, timeout, middleman

So I am doing a call to an API that keeps timing out even though I set a timeout of 1000 seconds its timeing out after 30, my implementation is probably wrong.

```
require 'HTTParty'
require 'json'


class Api
    include HTTParty
    default_timeout 1000

    @@Json

    def initialize(api_root_url, code)
        response = HTTParty.get("#{api_root_url}/api/page/"+code)
        @@Json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    end
end
```

error

/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill': Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)
from .rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in`rbuf_fill'
    from .rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
    from .rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in`readline'
    from .rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'
    from .rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in`read_new'
    from .rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1319:in `block in transport_request'
    from .rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in`catch'
    from .rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `transport_request'
    from .rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in`request'
    from .rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1286:in `block in request'
    from .rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in`start'
    from .rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `default_timeout` instead:

http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/ClassMethods#default_timeout-instance_method